# How to disable 'f10' camera indicator light on Asus Vivobook s16x with Ubuntu 22.04.1?

Tags: keyboard, asus, camera

So, I've installed  Ubuntu 22.04.1 on Asus Vivobook s16x and there's this issue: an indicator  for camera on f10 button (orange led) is always on. Is it possible to disable it somehow? I've tried to disable fn lock, press fn-f10, but nothing happens. Other fn combinations like control volume, brightness, micro work fine, but this one is broken - it doesn't turn on/off camera - it's always on. I've tried to unload camera module from the kernel - well, camera stopped working, but the led was still on. I've checked bios - there's nothing regarding leds. Any suggestions?

Comment: Similar issue here on a Zenbook UX3402ZA dual booted with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11; the shortcut keys seem to trigger their functions, but the indicators remain on whatever they were last set to on Windows. I'm no expert at this kinda stuff but looks like they're some "feature" similar to my touchpad/numpad that needs some sort of firmware to work/communicate with linux OSs maybe? Seems like a lot of Asus -book laptops have compatibility issues with Linux, especially in relation to drivers and devices (such as the incompatibility issues related to their ALC294 audio chip).

Comment: Thankfully, I haven't seen issues other than with this led

Answer (score 0):

Updating bios solved the issue.